# Yocto + boost. Is there any way to get libboost.a into the SDK?

Tags: c++, boost, yocto

Dear embedded Linux developers.

Recently I started implementing boost support in my Yocto BSP.
Such support requires boost library linked both static and dynamic.
I managed to successfully build it this way but there is one thing which spoils the SDK (for us).
Our software (which uses the SDK) required libboost.a static library to be present.
Tried almost everything but I can't make it build with Yocto, everything is build fine but libboost.a is not created.
However, buildroot makes it during his build - that means it can be done.

So the question is: is there any chance to make it build in Yocto?
Do I miss something in boost build configuration/options?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want some traction on this you might have to show a [mcve] in the form of some makefile snippets or whatever that show how you are referencing this API.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, and .a files are created and packaged during boost build:

```
$ ls -l tmp/deploy/rpm/i586/*boost*static*
-rw-r--r-- 3 a a 65204208 Feb  1 13:08 tmp/deploy/rpm/i586/boost-staticdev-1.69.0-r0.i586.rpm
```

If you want all -staticdev packages in the SDK for the libraries in your
image, add the following to your local.conf (or the image recipe, doesn't
matter which):

SDKIMAGE_FEATURES = "dev-pkgs dbg-pkgs staticdev-pkgs"

If you want a single staticdev package in the SDK you'd need to add the
following instead:

TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " boost-staticdev"

Comment: I already have staticdev-pkgs in SDK image features. Just re-check my build. boost-staticdev is there but it does not contain libboost.a It only contains a collection of .a libraries for all modules but not a trace of libboost.a

Comment: Then you need to inspect the boost source tree for how to enable the build of libboost.a. If that's all the individual libraries rolled together into one archive, linking with that would be a bad idea in my opinion, as it would use a lot of RAM while only a few (or even just one) libraries would be actually used.

Comment: That's is what I am looking at right now. Going to publish a way doing that for those who interested. When you talk about RAM, I guess you mean 'RAM usage during compile phase', right? Because linker should only use those components which are actually required, and not the whole content of such a big static lib IMO.